# HTML & CSS: <hr> alignment in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have got a problem with the alignment of an hr-element when I use the Internet Explorer. What I want to achieve is that the following lines are basically all centered on the page. There are two headlines, a horizontal line (200px wide), and a line of text with the name of the author.

HTML:

```
<h1>Headline 1</h2>             
<h2>Headline 2</h3>
<hr>
<p>Author name</p>
```

CSS:

```
> h1 {text-align: center;} 
> h2 {text-align: center;} 
> p  {text-align: center;} 
> hr {width: 200px; text-align: center;}
```

As you can see, I defined the hr-element in the CSS so that it should be centered - and it is, in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera. But every time I open the page with Microsoft's IE (version: 11, but also the mobile browser), the hr-element is aligned to the left side.

[image: Illustration]

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about trying this?

```
hr { display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

Comment: It's a plesaure :). Accept the answer if it worked for you